# ServicePointManager Monitoring HTTP Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, httprequest, servicepoint

I am working with an application that sends hundreds of HTTP requests a minute to different URIs. Is there any way to monitor the connections the application has created?  I found that the ServicePointManager is great for inspecting a particular domain, but it requires a URI to narrow the scope.  **My problems would be solved if the [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) exposed a listing of all connections currently being made and their concurrent connection counts.**

```
   Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
   ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
```

*Why do I want to do this?  I am trying to diagnose timeout exceptions on requests that have 30 seconds to complete and return simple JSON. (The timeout does not happen every on every request) It seems like there shouldn't be a reason for the timeout.  Maybe I am running out of available connections because I've exceeded the 96 I have available from the ServicePointManager, and thats my bottleneck.  While unlikely, thats the only thing I can come up with right now.  Suggestions?*

Comment: Is the application that sends the HTTP requests something you have the code to? Have you tried a network monitoring tool like fiddler?

Comment: Can you post the code that is creating the http requests. If you are creating them, there is a way to track them from there.

Comment: Also consider if you are not reusing connections you may end up with a lot closing in TIME_WAIT [msdn:Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx)

Comment: Good point. Thanks for making it

Answer (score 1):

What are you currently using? Windows Performance Monitor?

JPSanders in his excellent [blog post on ServicePointManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) suggests using [Netmon](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/p/downloads.aspx)